# Embedding a base 64 truetype font with @font-face in a svg file, does not work in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, svg, fonts, base64

I have a standalone SVG document without any external dependencies. I'm using a custom font embedded in base64.

I am embedding the font using @font-face like that:

```
@font-face{font-family:'a_e2ef524fbf3d9fe611d5a8e90fefdc9c';src:url(data:font/truetype;charset=utf-8;base64,[BASE64_CODE])format('truetype');font-weight:normal;font-style:normal;}
```

The font renders well in Chrome and FireFox but not in Internet Explorer (any version).

The windows properties shows that the font is installable.

I would appreaciate any help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved this issue, the problem was the length of the font name (a_e2ef524fbf3d9fe611d5a8e90fefdc9c).

It seems IE do not like names with more than 31 characters... I just change name to "aaa" and the font renders fine!

[See here for an example](http://When%20a%20font%20family%20name%20contains%20more%20than%2032%20characters%20all%20versions%20of%20Internet%20Explorer%20until%2011%20use%20the%20fallback%20font%20instead.) (open it with IE).